# How to keep the extension code of outbound dialing?

Tags: calls, phone-app, call-history, dialer-codes

We can dial `(555)555-5555,2000` so as to reach the extension code `2000` on Lollipop and later.

However, the call log shows only `(555)555-5555`. I tried a couple of call log apps and dialer apps, but it seems the same. This results in an inconvenience: I can not see to which extension I dialed when I see the logs (e.g. ext `2000` to John, or `2001` to Bob, etc).

Is there any setting or way to keep the extension number for outbound calling in the log?

Comment: I'd like to see this implemented into a dialler app again, like on android 2.3 with some phones...